# Cross Product Ratio Analysis

Tags: statistics, statistical-finance

Can you please advise?

I have been recently trying to sort this out for couple of days but cannot get the same numbers as previous authors:

The equation is shown in Agarwal and Naik *Multi-Period Performance Persistence Analysis of Hedge Funds* (2001) ([link](http://www2.gsu.edu/~fncvaa/Jfqapers.pdf)) as:

[image]

The question is why is there "sigma" and what does it represent?

I have seen the same equation written in the following way:

[image]

And again I can do ln(CPR) and the square root bit but the "sigma" appears again! I cannot do a stdev calculation because the CPR is a single number [that is if sigma represents standard deviation in this case?]

Can you advise what "sigma" may represent in here?

Comment: It's just a name for the expression on the right hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to the issue. I was using the mean of winners and loser instead of the total [correct] in computation of the CPR and Z-stat.

Comment: For me it's not quite clear what is happening here. Could you elaborate?